# Pythonic way to write long import statements

Tags: python, django, python-import

What is the pythonic way to import from Models (or Forms or views) in Django?

To say it frank I bluntly do this:

```
from myapp.models import foo, bar, foobar, barfoo, foofoo, barbar, barfoobar, thelistgoeson, and, on, andon...
```

It is far longer than the maximum of 79 characters - but what is the better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parentheses to group your imports together:

```
from myapp.models import (foo, bar, foobar, barfoo, foofoo,
    barbar, barfoobar, thelistgoeson, and, on, and, so, on)
```

This is in accordance with [PEP-328 Rationale for parentheses](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-parentheses):

> Currently, if you want to import a lot of names from a module or
>   package, you have to choose one of several unpalatable options:
>
> - Write a long line with backslash continuations:
> - Write multiple import statements:
>
> (`import *` is not an option ;-)
>
> Instead, it should be possible to use Python's standard grouping
>   mechanism (parentheses) to write the import statement:
>
> This part of the proposal had BDFL approval from the beginning.
>
> Parentheses support was added to Python 2.4.

Comment: I put the various names on separate lines and sort them. That way adding or removing names is far clearer in a diff.

Comment: I didn't knew that I could use parentheses - which now seems obviouse, duh. Now I have a seperate line for each name and a trailing comma on the last line for better readability in git and diff

Answer (score 2):

What about importing models?

```
from myapp import models

foo = models.foo
bar = models.bar
```

It is much shorter and you don't have to maintain a list of imports. You also get to have a namespace, and you can have local variables called `foo` and `bar`

Comment: `from myapp.models import foo` *already* creates a local variable named `foo`. That's what an import does: it binds values from an external modules to names in the current module's namespace. This code is actually *longer*, since you have to repeat the module name and module member for every local name. Only the individual lines are shorter.

Comment: I do know that. But you get to keep a namescape for each of these variables, which makes sense, rather than have all the local variables and your imports sharing the same namespace. It doesn't change much in the end, but that's what i try to use (it's not always possible)

Comment: You can use both imports, if I understand the distinction you are making: `from myapp import models` to have `models` in the local namespace to access things you don't subsequent import specifically, then `from myapp.models import (foo, bar, etc)` to import specific names.